# Bootstrap "form-horizontal" class not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2019, bootstrap-5

I am trying to learn Bootstrap and have run into a problem. I am building a simple ASP.net web form that I want to be horizontally aligned. From what I understand I should be able to add "form-horizontal" to the class attribute of my form element to achieve this. How ever this does not seem to work and intellisense is not even recognizing it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="XEx03Quotation.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>"Price Quotation"</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="Default" class="form-horizontal" runat="server">
        
        <main class="container">            
              
            <h1 class="jumbotron">Price Quotation</h1>
           
            <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="price $" class="col-3 lab control-label">Price $</label> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="price" name="price" runat="server" CssClass="col-3 form-control bold" ></asp:TextBox>                              
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="priceValid" CssClass="col-6 text-danger" runat="server" ControlToValidate="price" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="priceRangeValid" CssClass="col-6 text-danger" runat="server" ControlToValidate="price" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Price must be an integer between 10 and 1000" MaximumValue="1000" MinimumValue="10" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
            </div>
             
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="discountPercent" class="col-3 control-label">Discount Percent %</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="discountPercent" name="discountPercent" CssClass="col-3 form-control"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                            
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="discountPercentValid" class="col-6 text-danger" runat="server" ControlToValidate="discountPercent" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Required" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="discountPercentRangeValid" class="col-6 text-danger" runat="server" ControlToValidate="discountPercent" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="False" ErrorMessage="Discount percent must be an integer between 10 and 50" MaximumValue="50" MinimumValue="10" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="discountAmount" class="col-3">Discount Amount</label>
            <asp:Label ID="discountAmmount" CssClass="col-3 control-label bold" name="discountAmmount" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>             
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="totalPrice" class="col-3">Total Price</label> 
            <asp:Label ID="totalPrice" CssClass="col-3 control-label bold" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
            </div>
              
            <div class="form-group offset-3" >  
            <asp:Button ID="calcTotBttn" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Calculate" />
            </div>    
        </main>
       
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I do have the latest version of bootstrap installed. Any Ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating Horizontal Form in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555056/creating-horizontal-form-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: Yes and no. I now realize that .form-horizontal is not supported by bootstrap 4 and 5 but I still cant seem to find the correct syntax for bootstrap 5 to achieve the desired results.  I've tried using .md-3 class as well as wrapping as follows: <div class="row"><div class="col">CodeBlock</div></div> and neither works. I cant find any other solution.

Comment: So there is some info on GetBootstrap about things that are dropped between v4 and v5. One useful item that seems to be getting dropped is `form-inline` which would have suited you perfectly I think. The Docs are here for that news https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms . What they suggest now is to use their Grid system to make an in-line layout. Those Docs are here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/